# I cannot verify of the $_POST[''];

Tags: php, post

I wrote this code but I have an problem. I can not verify if there is no file uploaded when anyone hit submit and I can not specific the allowed extinsion for example ".jpg". How can I do this in "foreach", I can do this when I upload just one image but this code for multi upload and if have you noticed i have used array in the form.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root')or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('storeimage');
?>
<?
if ($_POST['submit'] ){
  $file=$_FILES['file'];
  $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  foreach($name as $key=>$value){
    $name_file=$name[$key];
    $tmp_file=$tmp_name[$key];
    $imgpath = rand().'.jpeg'; 

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,'images/'.$imgpath);

    $insert=mysql_query("insert into  imagelocation values('','images/$imgpath')")or die (mysql_error());
    $id=mysql_insert_id();

    $select=mysql_query("select * from  imagelocation where id='$id' ");

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($select)){
      echo "<center><img src='$row->images'/></center><br/>";
    }
  }
}
?>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='file[]' multiple />
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: off topic, but important: PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete. The PHP manual **strongly** recommends not using them, and using the `mysqli_xxx()` functions instead (or the PDO library). Switching to the `mysqli_xx()` functions is very easy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You must have a powerful aversion to whitespace :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You work with multiple files you need to do something like this

```
$allowedExt  = array("jpg");
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    foreach ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $file ) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
            $fileTemp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"][$key];
            $fileExt = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fileExt = strtolower($fileExt);

            if(!in_array($fileExt, $allowedExt))
            {
                // extention not supported ;
                continue;
            }

            // do your magic



        } else {
            // Somethign bad happend 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact i would like to thank you for your help to me and you are really good programmer thank you again and thank for all guys who try's to help me

Answer (score 0):

never did it that way, but propably it's like

```
foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $file) {

    // echo $file['name'] . '<br>';
}
```